# Tracing a Stroke with UIViewAnimation

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview, core-animation

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef s = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(s, 250, 5, 5, 1);
    CGContextFillRect(s, CGRectMake(2, 2, 2, 2));

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:s];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: .5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    //animation goes here
    vector<CGPoint>::iterator L = dp.dPoints->begin();
    while(L != dp.dPoints->end()){
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(s, (*L).x, (*L).y);
        ++L;
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

What i would like to do is take a rectangle made in CGContext and with the use of UIViews animation, it trace (in an endless Animation) a stroke line created with CGContext.
I am rather unsure how i would go about tracing my line...
Any help, links or comments would be great thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blog.devedup.com/index.php/2010/03/03/iphone-animate-an-object-along-a-path/

**draw a curved line**

```
    //This draws a quadratic bezier curved line right across the screen
    - ( void ) drawACurvedLine {
        //Create a bitmap graphics context, you will later get a UIImage from this
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320,460));
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        //Set variables in the context for drawing
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.5);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);

        //Set the start point of your drawing
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 10, 10);
        //The end point of the line is 310,450 .... i'm also setting a reference point of 10,450
        //A quadratic bezier curve is drawn using these coordinates - experiment and see the results.
        CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(ctx, 10, 450, 310, 450);
        //Add another curve, the opposite of the above - finishing back where we started
        CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(ctx, 310, 10, 10, 10);

        //Draw the line
        CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathStroke);

        //Get a UIImage from the current bitmap context we created at the start and then end the image context
        UIImage *curve = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        //With the image, we need a UIImageView
        UIImageView *curveView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:curve];
        //Set the frame of the view - which is used to position it when we add it to our current UIView
        curveView.frame = CGRectMake(1, 1, 320, 460);
        curveView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:curveView];
    }
```

**keyframe animation, and a path that is the same as the line we just drew. We will also draw a circle, and animate it along that path:**

```
- (void) animateCicleAlongPath {
    //Prepare the animation - we use keyframe animation for animations of this complexity
    CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    //Set some variables on the animation
    pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
    //We want the animation to persist - not so important in this case - but kept for clarity
    //If we animated something from left to right - and we wanted it to stay in the new position,
    //then we would need these parameters
    pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    pathAnimation.duration = 5.0;
    //Lets loop continuously for the demonstration
    pathAnimation.repeatCount = 1000;

    //Setup the path for the animation - this is very similar as the code the draw the line
    //instead of drawing to the graphics context, instead we draw lines on a CGPathRef
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(310, 450);
    CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, 10, 10);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, 10, 450, 310, 450);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, 310, 10, 10, 10);

    //Now we have the path, we tell the animation we want to use this path - then we release the path
    pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
    CGPathRelease(curvedPath);

    //We will now draw a circle at the start of the path which we will animate to follow the path
    //We use the same technique as before to draw to a bitmap context and then eventually create
    //a UIImageView which we add to our view
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(20,20));
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //Set context variables
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.5);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    //Draw a circle - and paint it with a different outline (white) and fill color (green)
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(1, 1, 18, 18));
    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFillStroke);
    UIImage *circle = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageView *circleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:circle];
    circleView.frame = CGRectMake(1, 1, 20, 20);
    [self addSubview:circleView];

    //Add the animation to the circleView - once you add the animation to the layer, the animation starts
    [circleView.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"moveTheSquare"];
}
```

**To get all this running, you can use this init method:**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    [self drawACurvedLine];
    [self animateCicleAlongPath];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**and use something like this in your ViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIView *customView = [[Canvas alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:customView];
    [customView release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

**Also…don’t forget to add your Quartz import:**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```